# Issues with Electron FCM App on Win 11 enterprise Token Generated, but Notifications Not Received

Tags: windows, electron, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an Electron FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) app based on the electron-fcm-demo sample. The app is working well on most devices, but I'm encountering a specific issue on a **Windows 11 Enterprise** edition device.

The problem is as follows:

The app successfully generates an FCM token on the problematic Windows 11 Enterprise device.
When triggering a notification, the notification is not received on this specific device.
However, if I create a new user on the same device and run the app with the new user, a new FCM token is generated, and notifications are received successfully.

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

1.Checked device permissions for push notifications.
2.Verified a stable internet connection on the problematic device.
3.Reviewed logs and error messages on both the client and server sides, but no specific issues were identified.
4.Ensured that the app has necessary background execution permissions.
5.Reinstalled the app on the problematic device, but the FCM token remained the same.

I'm seeking advice on how to understand and address this behavior, especially the difference in receiving notifications between the original and newly created users on the same device.

Thank you for your assistance!